# Assigning an (x,y) position to svg element when loading with Snap

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I have successfully loaded an SVG element onto my webpage and it displays correctly. 
The problem is that I need it to be in a certain position on my page. Since I am not loading it through html, I cannot assign a div and modify position using css.

I have taken a look through Snap.svg API references and some examples. It has pointed me into trying `Element.attr`.

I am also aware of using `Element.animate({transform: 'tx,y'});` but I am looking for a solution of initial placement upon loading.

Here is my code along with what I tried:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var s = Snap(800,800);
    Snap.load( "/svg/RedBar-01.svg", function( f ) {
        s.append( f ); //add the loaded svg fragment into the DOM
        var element = s.select('#line');
        element.animate({
            fill: "purple",
        }, 1000);

        element.attr({
            x:100,   //Setting this 
            y:500    // or this doesnt seem to change the position at all
        });
        //Find out how to position this element..
    });
```

Does anyone have an idea of how I can assign an (x,y) position for my svg element? Thanks for any help I can get.

Here is the svg file code to make it more clear of what I am working with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 20.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="redBar" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 113.9 3.7" style="enable-background:new 0 0 113.9 3.7;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">

</style>
<g id="line">

        <linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="1.239177e-04" y1="29.3381" x2="113.9399" y2="29.3381" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 1.3293 0 -37.1699)">
        <stop  offset="1.075269e-02" style="stop-color:#EC1C24"/>
        <stop  offset="0.1548" style="stop-color:#EC2026"/>
        <stop  offset="0.2961" style="stop-color:#ED2C2A"/>
        <stop  offset="0.436" style="stop-color:#EE3F32"/>
        <stop  offset="0.5" style="stop-color:#EF4B37"/>
        <stop  offset="0.5483" style="stop-color:#EE4334"/>
        <stop  offset="0.7058" style="stop-color:#ED2D2B"/>
        <stop  offset="0.8586" style="stop-color:#EC2026"/>
        <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#EC1C24"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <path class="st0" d="M113,3.7H1c-0.5,0-1-0.4-1-1L0,1c0-0.5,0.4-1,1-1l112,0c0.5,0,1,0.4,1,1v1.7C113.9,3.2,113.5,3.7,113,3.7z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: how about element.attr({transform: 'translate(100, 500)';}) or element.transform('t 100 500');

Comment: @RobertLongson Hey, thanks for the reply. I tried both of your suggestions which does move my svg element around. But doesnt that just shift the coordinates from where it seems to randomly spawn on my page rather than start from (0,0) on the top left of the page?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you create a fiddle or something to show what the problem is?

Comment: Just a guess but it sounds like the problem you are having isn't that the element in the SVG is positioned wrong but that the SVG box itself is not where you want it. If you want it in the top left of the page then maybe you need to give the svg box a class and make that class position:absolute;top:0;left:0 or something like that?

Comment: @AustinC What you are saying sounds about right. When you say I need to give the svg box a class; is this within the svg file? And do I modify the css within the file as well? I edited post to include svg file code.

Comment: I just noticed that you are creating a new SVG with Snap. I would recommend that you instead place an empty SVG element in your HTML directly like: <svg viewbox='0 -25 785 625' id='svg'></svg> Then use var s=Snap(#svg) instead of Snap(800,800) like you are doing now. Everything will be the same but you have complete control over your SVG tag - you can add a class to it, or add CSS to it directly or etc.

Comment: @AustinC Okay, I was able to do as you said. I placed it in HTML like this: `<div class = "bar"> <svg viewbox='0 -25 785 625' id='svg'></svg>
</div>`  Although, modifying CSS elements such as `top` and `left` are giving me unexpected results. For example, setting those to '0' are not placing the element on top left of the page.